# How to convert List of this order to json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

Im having list as shown:

```
 text = ['block 1 = HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop', 'block 2 = 15-dk0049TX', 'block 3 = Serial No']
```

i want output as { "block 1" : "HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop", "block 2" : 15-dk0049TX, "block 3" : "Serial No"}

How to convert above list to key-value pairing in json ?

Comment: can you give any sample of output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` with `dict`

**Ex:**

```
text = ['block 1 = HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop', 'block 2 = 15-dk0049TX', 'block 3 = Serial No']
result = dict(i.split(" = ") for i in text)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'block 1': 'HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop',
 'block 2': '15-dk0049TX',
 'block 3': 'Serial No'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import json

text = ['block 1 = HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop', 'block 2 = 15-dk0049TX', 'block 3 = Serial No']
json_str = json.dumps(text)
sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(json_str))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

If you want a key-value pairing, instead, please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: i made changes, please go through the question as i want json in above order

Comment: It looks like you got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import json

text = ['block 1 = HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop', 'block 2 = 15-dk0049TX', 'block 3 = Serial No']
json_dic = [{t.split('=')[0].strip(): t.split('=')[1].strip()} for t in text]
print(json.dumps(json_dic))
```